Rendering Google Ads in localhost Gatsby.js project
I'm working on a Gatsby.js project that displays ads correctly in production, but not in localhost.
An iframe is supposed to be inserted into the Ad component via a script that is generated by the 'gatsby-browser.js' file. To facilitate this, I've also added another script in the 'gatsby-ssr.js' file to append Google Tags to the Window object, since I was having trouble doing this via the 'onClientEntry' function.
So far, I can generate the required Window objects, and append the script tag to the head tag in the HTML document, but still cannot generate the iframe.
Ad component
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class Ad extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const script=document.createElement('script')
    script.src=`${adEmbedCodeURL}`
    script.defer=true;
    script.setAttribute("data-can-ad","true")
    this.instance.appendChild(script)
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className=`${class-name}` ref={el => (this.instance = el)} >
        <p>Advertisement</p>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default AdMPU

gatsby-browser.js
export const onClientEntry= () => {
if (typeof __canGDPR == 'function') { 
    console.log('onClientEntry')
    window.__canGDPR(function() {
      console.log('onClientEntry - CANS')
      var createScript = function(url, callback) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        if (callback) {
          script.onload = callback; 
        }document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(script);
      };
      createScript(`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${containerID}`);
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){
        window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', `${containerID}`);
    });
};
}

export const onRouteUpdate = () => {
    console.log('onRouteUpdate');
if (typeof __canGDPR == 'function') { 
    window.__canGDPR(function() {
      console.log('onRouteUpdate - CANS')
      var createScript = function(url, callback) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        if (callback) {
          script.onload = callback; 
        }document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].appendChild(script);
      };
      createScript(`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${containerID}`);
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){
        window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', `${containerID}`);
    });
};
}

gatsby-ssr.js
import React from 'react'

export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
    setHeadComponents ([
    <script
      key="SGCCansAds"
      src=`${adEmbedCodeURL}`
    />,
    <script 
      key="jQuery" 
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    />,
    <script
    key="gtm-script"
    async
    src=`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${containerID}`
  />,
  <script
    key="gtm-initializer"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){ window.dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', `${containerID}`);
      `,
    }}
  />,
  ])
}

